# Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0) error

Tags: mobile-development, android-sdk-2.3, flutter-doctor

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
I have been trying to resolve this issue on my windows 11 machine but have been failing every time, I had even uninstalled my android studio and even after re installation it was still a fail

I expected after I ran the flutter doctor there would be no error on the andorid sdk check.

Comment: Can you edit to clarify what the error is and when it's happening? Could Google the partial error message included, but guessing that A, B, C other issues are the same and finding they're not and that could've been more clear is a waste of time and energy.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.